# JQuery Chosen plugin - Return to "Select an option"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have this simple select where I apply Chosen plugin

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="reset" value="reset">Reset</label>

<select id="listclient">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Mark">Mark</option>
<option value="Jenny">Jenny</option>
<option value="Joy"></option>
</select>
```

And in JS:

```
$("#listclient").chosen({width:"100%",no_results_text: "No results",placeholder_text_single: "Select client"});
```

It works great but I want when I click radiobutton "reset" return to placerholder text single "Select client" by default.

I would like some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the select using:

```
$('#listclient').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I would advise to change the radio element to button instead.

```js
$(function () {
 $("#listclient").chosen({ width: "100%", no_results_text: "No results", placeholder_text_single: "Select client" });

 $("[name='reset']").on("click", function () {
  $('#listclient').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.min.css" />

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="reset" value="reset">Reset</label>

<select id="listclient">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
 <option value="Jenny">Jenny</option>
 <option value="Joy"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that probably shouldn't be a `radio` input at all, it should probably just be a button.

But more to the point, I would add a `$().click` handler for the reset button that does something like `$('#listclient').val('')`